# Why vectorDB did not return right answer from the data embeded multiple CSV files

Tags: python, csv, embedding, langchain

I’m prototyping the chatbot that retrieves many CSV files. This CSV file has the field title, videoId(Youtube), text (description + transcription). I splitted the text into 100 tokens by using CharacterTextSplitter.from_tiktoken_encoder() in Langchain. So each CSV has a structure like the following.  All videos are about cars.

videoId0_0.csv :  title0 | videoId0 | text_chunk0

videoId0_1.csv :  title0 | videoId0 | text_chunk1

videoId0_2.csv :  title0 | videoId0 | text_chunk1

videoId1_0.csv : title1 | videoId1 | text_chunk0

videoId1_0.csv: title1 | videoId1 | text_chunk1

videoId1_0.csv: title1 | videoId1 | text_chunk1

An example of CSV is like following.

```
title,videoId,text
남자들이 꼽는 최고의 세단 ... BMW 신형 5시리즈 프리뷰 / 오토뷰., SiKVRD6fgIU, ★ 오토뷰 시승기는?.....
```

I load these CSV files into Chroma DB as Vector store like the following.

```py
    import os 
    from langchain.chains import RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain
    from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
    from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
    from langchain.embeddings.sentence_transformer import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
    from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
    
    
    
    data_path = os.path.join( os.getcwd(), 'duplicated_data' )
    loader = DirectoryLoader(data_path, glob="*.csv")
    docs = loader.load()
    
    embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
    
    # load it into Chroma
    db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embedding_function, persist_directory="./chroma_db")
```

And I queried data by `similarity()`  like the following.

```
answers = db2.similarity_search("BMW")
```

But it returns data not relevant to my query, e.g. Benz,  Hyundai, or no content about BMW in the returned data.  What’s the problem?